# Extjs 5. Ext.application is not a function. Why?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I get an error in console: `Ext.application is not a function`. My `index.html` file contains this code:

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.0.1/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css" />
<script src="/ext-5.0.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>    
...
```

While `app.js` has just this code, taken from one demo:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'AM',
appFolder: 'app',
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Users',
                html : 'List of users will go here'
        }]
    });
}
});
```

**EDIT**

By the way, even running "official" `/ext-5.0.1/examples/app/simple/simple.html` I get the same error. Why is that?

Comment: your code works fine on my side,try here https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Are you sure that's the only error?  This declaration usually exists in a global context - if there is another issue it may be killing the entire page.

Comment: Well, whatever I do, I still get this error. But when I change to Ext 4.1.1 version, then everything is ok. Can this be some kind of prohibition? I mean, you have to have a commercial license to use such kind of coding. Or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the call to `Ext.application` inside an `Ext.onReady` block.

```
// app.js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
      Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
          xtype: 'panel',
          title: 'Users',
          html : 'List of users will go here'
        }]
      });
    }
  });
})
```

The reason this is necessary, BTW, is that the ext-all-debug.js files doesn't contain all of ExtJS. It contains the bootstrap code - the code that knows how to get everything else. Part of that "everything else" is the application code. So until that's had a chance to run, Ext.application doesn't exist.

The portal example you mention works because it uses the result of a `sencha app build` - the `microloader.js`. This loads up a full version of ExtJS (or rather, the parts used in the app), and thus Ext.application is already defined by the time it's used. (The same goes with Sencha Fiddle - you wouldn't need the Ext.onReady there either)

Comment: Sorry, do you have a commercial version of the product or a public one?

Comment: Well, wrapping inside Ext.onReady has no effect

Comment: Well, let's try the "stupid question" solution - is it successfully loading the `/ext-5.0.1/ext-all-debug.js` file?

The other possibility is that, because you're using the nightly build, you may have a broken version. Try it with the 5.0.0 release.

Comment: Yes, it is successfully loading it, because `Ext.application is not a function` is the only error I see in the console. I will now check 5.0.0 release

Comment: Well, it is a really strange thing. I've just checked 5.0.0 release and here is what I've got. Examples from examples/app/  folder are not running for the same reason - `Ext.application is not a function`, but an example from portal folder is running ok.

Comment: Okay - I just tried the simple app demo in the examples, and I got the problem you described. I then updated the app.js file so that the call to Ext.application is done onReady, and it worked.

I'm updating my answer with more details.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Although, my own code does not work with this trick, the code in examples/app/ started to run. I will take them as a stepping stone.

Comment: Someone put you a minus for some reason, but I voted up and checked your answer as a solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
<script src="/ext-5.0.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

You should use

```
<script src="/ext-5.0.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

The second one contains all Components and Classes as expected.