# Ext.application is undefined in Ext 5

Tags: javascript, extjs

I had an Ext application which worked fine in Ext 4, but I get error in ext 5. I am loading `ext-all.js` fine.

```
Ext.application({  // undefined method here

});
```

What else I need to load?

Comment: does this help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038776/extjs-5-ext-application-is-not-a-function-why

Answer (score 1):

If you provided more code so we could see where your error is, would be preferable. But answering your question, the minimum you neeed is:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'MyApp', // Your app name here

    launch : function() {
        // Your code here 
        Ext.Msg.alert('Test', 'Hello World!');
    }
});
```

if this code doesn't work, you probably have not imported all files needed.